# Need to show my app content in lock screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create an android app same as like this unlockar to display my app contents in lock screen.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.unlockar.com&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

The following alert dialog was launched from a broadcast reciever,and it showed when screen was helped.Modify to suit your needs

```
//required permissions in manifest
<uses-permission   android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
      <uses-permission   android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
      <uses-permission   android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>

//code in my broadcast
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            Window window = (Window) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

            PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "tag");
            wl.acquire();
        }
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                                    .setTitle("On lock dialog message")
                                    .setMessage(""Notice")
                                    .create();

                            alertDialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
                            alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
                            alertDialog.show();
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: This is working after unlocking the screen only. @peter

Comment: did you add the permissions?

Comment: when are you trying to show the content,via a service or?

Comment: via service by alarmmanager event fired in broadcastreceiver.

Answer (score 0):

you should use this flag:**FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED**
example:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

Comment: already it is there `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);` but it is working after unlocking the screen only.

Comment: make sure to use this flag too: **FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD**

Comment: and don't forget to add the permission in your mainfest:

` <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
`

and add this line to activity that will appear in your manifest:

`android:showOnLockScreen="true"`